# Better usage of 'it'

Tags: grammar

Can the experts please weigh in on this?

I think there are two typos in this statement. Am I correct?

"There are plans to add support for such categories Python, but it
unfortunately looks like they won’t be realized in the near future."

should be changed to

"There are plans to add support for such categories **to** Python, but
unfortunately **it** looks like they won’t be realized in the near future."

We need to add a "to" before "Python", and "it" should be moved to appear after "unfortunately". While placing the "it" before "unfortunately" is grammatically correct, it's not standard English and that's not how a native speaker of English would speak or write. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Alert! Proof-reading Qs may be OT here.

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic if the source of concern isn't identified. Here, the main source of concern *is* identified - the location of the word "it".

Comment: Both locations for "it" are used by native speakers. (About "to", yes, something should go there, unless the speaker is addressing someone called *Python*.)

Answer (score 1):

The statement definitely needs "to" inserted before Python.

On the placement of "it":
In the sentence, "unfortunately" is a comment on the entire statement "....won't be realized in the near future." So "unfortunately" is best placed at the beginning or end, not in the middle at all:

"...but it looks like they won’t be realized in the near future, unfortunately."

or as two sentences:

"There are plans to add support for such categories to Python. Unfortunately, it looks like they won’t be realized in the near future."

Keep in mind that "native speakers," when speaking (not writing), often put qualifiers like "only", "even", "just" and similar restrictive words in the wrong place. This can actually change meaning, but is not confusing to most listeners. That's not exactly applicable to your sentence, but it is relevant in the sense that word order might upset the natural rhythm of a sentence, but does not really upset comprehension. Rhythm is important for good writing, but comprehension is the most important.

Comment: And the other typo: "There are plans to add support for categories such as Python" or "There are plans to add support for such categories as Python", not "There are plans to add support for such categories Python"

Comment: Actually, it's about adding the concept of "categories" to the Python programming language, I believe. The "to" was missing, and I also left it out of my second suggested sentence above.